Exercise 5.A.11 in Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th edition, Sheldon Axler.
This is exercise 11 which comes from Linear Algebra Done Right, Section 5A, 4th edition, Sheldon Axler.

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, and $\alpha
\in \mathbf{F}$. Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $T -\lambda I$ is invertible for all $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$ such that $0 < |\alpha - \lambda| < \delta$.

Here, $\mathbf{F}$ denotes either the set of real numbers or complex numbers. I'm not sure where to start with this exercise. Here's a few things I know, but don't know how to use for this problem:

$\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue $\iff T -\lambda I$ is
invertible
$T$ has at most $\text{dim} \ V$ distinct eigenvalues.

Could someone provide a hint to get me started?

Is it given that $A := T - \lambda I$ is invertible? If so, you can use the geometric series formula to write $(A + rI)^{-1}$ .

@Kakashi I don't think so. The way I'm interpreting the question is that we must find a $\delta > 0$ in order for $T - \lambda I$ to be invertible.

I see, the finite-dimensionality is key. Note $T - \lambda I$ is invertible if and only if $p(\lambda) = \det(T - \lambda I) \neq 0$. Since $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n = \dim(V)$, the result follows.

What is F? Supposedly a field with a real-valued absolute value operation, so I guess that would be a subfield of $\Bbb C$. Why not just take $\Bbb C$?

Plot your $\dim V$ eigenvalues in the complex plane. Now describe the eligible $\lambda$s and figure out what $\delta$ will work.

@Kakashi I haven't touched determinants yet; it comes last in this textbook. But please leave your comment here for future reference. Thank you!

@BrianMoehring added it!

This has little to do with linear algebra. There are only finitely many eigenvalues, so if there are any eigenvalues distinct from $\alpha$, there is one such eigenvalue$~\mu$ with $|\alpha-\mu|$ minimal among them. Then if you take $\delta$ to be that minimal absolute value, there are by construction no eigenvalues$~\lambda$ with $0<|\alpha-\lambda|<\delta$. Of course if there are no eigenvalues distinct from $\alpha$ at all, you can take whatever positive $\delta$ you like,

I think I'm following what you laid out. What I'm confused about is the exercise asks for all $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$, not just the eigenvalues. Is this implemented in your solution?

@PaulAsh Replace "$T-\lambda I$ is invertible" by the equivalent "$\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$", and it says "for all $\lambda$ with $0<|\alpha-\lambda|<\delta$, $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$" which I took the liberty to rephrase as "there are no eigenvalues$~\lambda$ of $T$ that satisfy $0<|\alpha-\lambda|<\delta$".

To simplify thinks lets ignore $\alpha$ for the time being (or assume $\alpha=0$
$T-\lambda I$ is invertible if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.
Suppose T has no non-zero eigenvalues.
Let $\mu$ be the eigenvalue of the smallest absolute value.
For all $\lambda$ where $|\lambda| < |\mu|,$
$\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue.  And $T-\lambda I$ is non singular.
But, suppose $T$ is zero and has an eigenvalue equal to $0.$
Then, again with $\mu$ as the non-zero eigenvalue of the smallest absolute value
With $0<|\lambda| < |\mu|$ again $\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue.
Re-introducing $\alpha$...
For any $\alpha$ (which may or may not be an eigenvalue), there is some available neighborhood around $\alpha$ such that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.

"Non-zero" should be "non-$\alpha$".

@MarcvanLeeuwen I was trying to introduce the idea considering $\alpha=0$ (by not even discussing $\alpha$) to show that there should be some available neighborhood of $\lambda$ in this simplified case, and once that has been introduced, can be generalized to any $\alpha$

I need some time digesting your solution. I will respond back with any questions sometime this week. Thank you.

Thanks for your answer. Couldn't there exist $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$ such that $|\mu| < |\lambda|$?

@PaulAsh That isn't what you have to show.  You have to show that there exists a $\delta$ such that $0< |\alpha - \lambda| < \delta \cdots$  This is more a question of real analysis than it is linear algebra.

I see. So we're only interested in $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$ which satisfies $0< |\alpha - \lambda| < \delta$? The wording of the question confused me.

Since $\dim V =n$, $T$ can have up to $n$ different eigenvalues, written in decreasing order as $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$.
Therefore for $\lambda>\lambda_1$ or $\lambda<\lambda_n$, $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.
It is also the case that if $\lambda \in (\lambda_{i+1},\lambda_{i})$ then $T-\lambda I$ is invertible. Denote $\frac{\lambda_i+\lambda_{i+1}}{2}$ as $\alpha$ and $\frac{\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}}{2}>0$ as $\delta$. Then if $|\alpha-\lambda|<\delta$, $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.
